# Assetic dump trigger [Twig_Error_Loader]

Tags: symfony, assetic

when I try to generate the css and javascript file for my production mode :

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

I got the following issue

```
[Twig_Error_Loader] 
The "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/vendor/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/Sy  
mfony/Bundle/SwiftmailerBundle/Resources/views" directory does not exist.
```

Yes indeed it doesn't exist. Anyway why is it looking for this file?

.

FOR FURTHER INFORMATION I USE THE FOLLOWING VERSION

Copy paste of my composer.json file

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.4.*@dev"
},
```

I update component with composer but still got the same issue.

Comment: in my sf installation the folder exists and contain the files `Collector\swiftmailer.html.twig`

Comment: I have Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/vendor/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/**Ressources/views/Collector/swiftmailer.html.twig** Could you please give me the path you have from the begining

Comment: OK it is working now. I forgot to clear the cache for the prod environement.

Comment: Hi @Aleqxs you are welcome, can i post as an answer so you can close your question?

Comment: yes of course. still got a probleme with assetic as I got not a unique file like this: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/618e85b.css" type="text/css" />  but   many different line with <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/618e85b_part_1_oneOfMycssFile_1.css" type="text/css" />

Comment: Hell, yes! I had the exact same problem. Clearing prod caches worked. @Alexis_D you should answer your own question because not everybody is reading comments. :)